# CSS Animation onClick

Tags: javascript, css, animation, click, onclick

How can I get a CSS Animation to play with a JavaScript onClick? I currently have:

```
.classname {
  -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
}
```

How can I apply an onClick?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Are you sure you only display your page on webkit? Here is the code, passed on safari.
The image `(id='img')` will rotate after button click.

```js
function ani() {
  document.getElementById('img').className = 'classname';
}
```

```css
.classname {
  -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="" type="button" onclick="ani()" value="Click">
<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vghKS.png" width="328" height="328" />
```

Comment: Just be mindful that using `.className` will wipe out all of your other classes on the given element. If this is undesired, use `document.getElementById('img').classList.add('classname');`

Comment: This animates only the first time уоu click. Subsequent clicks do nothing. Use `sad comrade` method below to enable multiple clicks.

Answer (score 66):

You just use the [`:active` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes). This is set when you click on any element.

```
.classname:active {
    /* animation css */
}
```

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I *think* Ravi's answer will work for you in that case.

Comment: This was very useful to me. It ran the animation only while the user was holding down the mouse button which was exactly what I needed.

Comment: This is what I needed too.

Comment: Thank you for this Answer, Which was exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 36):

Found solution on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

```
const element = document.getElementById('img')

element.classList.remove('classname'); // reset animation
void element.offsetWidth; // trigger reflow
element.classList.add('classname'); // start animation
```

Comment: Triggering the reflow on the middle line is a nifty trick. just what i needed

Comment: How does triggering the reflow work?

Comment: @he77kat_ I don't even know what reflow means, nor can I find a good explanation.  Care to oblige?

Comment: @ptrcao reflow is the name of the web browser process for re-calculating the positions and geometries of the elements in the HTML document, for the purpose of re-rendering part or all of the document. Certain browser APIs or doc properties cause this process to restart, and `elem.offsetWidth` is one of them

Comment: is there an equivalent of this for opacity?

Answer (score 24):

You can achieve this by binding an onclick listener and then adding the animate class like this:

```
$('#button').onClick(function(){
    $('#target_element').addClass('animate_class_name');
});
```

Comment: Basically, what you're telling jQuery to do is the following:
First line: jQuery targets the element that has ID of button, and creates a function for when the user clicks the element.
Second line: This is the element that'll get effected by the click. It targets the element with an id of target_element, and adds the class animate_class_name to that element.

Trust me, this solution works, I've used it in the past.

Answer (score 19):

## CSS ONLY solution that works on every click and plays the animation to the end:

All you have to do is to add the animation to the  `:focus` pseudo class and set it to none  in `:active` pseudo class.

If your element isn't focusable add `tabindex="0"` attribute to the html element:

```css
@keyframes beat {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8,0.8);
            transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  }
}
.className {
  background-color:#07d;  
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin:5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
          transform: scale(1, 1);
}
.className:focus {
  -webkit-animation: beat 1s ease-in-out backwards;
          animation: beat 1s ease-in-out backwards;
}
.className:active {
  -webkit-animation: none;
          animation: none;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>Any element with tabindex="0", like a div:</h3>
<div tabindex="0" class="className"> Click me many times!</div>
<h3>Any focusable element like a button:</h3>
<button class="className"> Click me many times!</button>
```

Comment: the one issue I see with this: if I click either of the demo controls then switch tabs, then switch back, the animation plays without clicking it.

Comment: it also animates if you press tab

Answer (score 6):

```js
var  abox = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
function allmove(){
        abox.classList.remove("move-ltr");
        abox.classList.remove("move-ttb");
       abox.classList.toggle("move");
}
function ltr(){
        abox.classList.remove("move");
        abox.classList.remove("move-ttb");
       abox.classList.toggle("move-ltr");
}
function ttb(){
       abox.classList.remove("move-ltr");
       abox.classList.remove("move");
       abox.classList.toggle("move-ttb");
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.move{
  -webkit-animation: moveall 5s;
  animation: moveall 5s;
}
.move-ltr{
   -webkit-animation: moveltr 5s;
  animation: moveltr 5s;
}
.move-ttb{
    -webkit-animation: movettb 5s;
  animation: movettb 5s;
}
@keyframes moveall {
  0%   {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
  25%  {left: 200px; top: 0px;}
  50%  {left: 200px; top: 200px;}
  75%  {left: 0px; top: 200px;}
  100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes moveltr {
  0%   { left: 0px; top: 0px;}
  50%  {left: 200px; top: 0px;}
  100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes movettb {
  0%   {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
  50%  {top: 200px;left: 0px;}
  100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button onclick="allmove()">click</button>
<button onclick="ltr()">click</button>
<button onclick="ttb()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a

```
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
```

to your CSS file, then you can control whether the animation is running or not by using this JS line:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

if you want the animation to run once, every time you click. Remember to set

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using following code

```
$('#button_id').on('click', function(){
$('#element_want_to_target').addClass('.animation_class');});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div>
 <p onclick="startAnimation()">Start</p><!--O botão para iniciar (start)-->
 <div id="animation">Hello!</div> <!--O elemento que você quer animar-->
</div>

<style>
@keyframes animationName {
from {margin-left:-30%;}
}
</style>

<script>
function startAnimation() {
    document.getElementById("animation").style.animation = "animationName 2s linear 1";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the animation and remove it after the animation-duration ends using setTimeout()

```
const elem = document.querySelector(".element");
elem.onclick = () => {
    elem.style.animation="YOUR_ANIMATION";
    setTimeout(()=>{
        elem.style.animation="none";
    },YOUR_ANIMATION_DURATION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function start(){
  document.querySelector('#popup-promocoes').style.bottom='-110px';
  document.querySelector('#popup-promocoes').style.display='flex';
  document.querySelector('#popup-promocoes').classList.add('dv-promocoes-show');
}
```

```css
.dv-promocoes-show {
  animation-name: up;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes up {
  from {opacity:0;bottom:-200px;}
  to {opacity:0.7;bottom:-10px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-promocoes" style="position:fixed;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:black;display:none;">
</div>
<button onclick="start()">Show</button>
```