# iframe overlay onclick transform

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, onclick, transform

just wonder if i'm on the right track...and maybe some help
referring to this question 
[CSS Animation onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847996/css-animation-onclick)

```
    $(#alpha).onClick(function({
    $('#alpha').addClass('.blowup');});

.blowup {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
     -o-transform: scale(1.5);
        transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

this isn't working -> http://jsfiddle.net/HQjMc/50/
something with z-index? i do have an a href onclick overlay that doesn't seem to affect the target iframe...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution:

#### HTML

```
<div id='alpha'>
    <iframe src="http://time.is"></iframe>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
#alpha {
    opacity:0.38;
    filter:alpha(opacity=38);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 

    -moz-transform:scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform:scale(0.25);
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0 
}

#alpha:hover {
    opacity:0.38;
    filter:alpha(opacity=38);

    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
         -o-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
}

#alpha > iframe {
    positon:fixed;
    zoom:1;
}
```

#### Example

the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/7nF2t/)

*ps: this will not work on internet explorer*

​

Comment: wow awesome, sure appreciate it. i'll look it over in a bit kinda busy though, thanks.