# Apply Css Animation to a class with onclick Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a this script :

```
function ani(){
    document.getElementById('para').className ='exeInputapparition';
}
```

To apply a css animation on my element who has the ID `para`.
It's working but i wanted to know if it's possible to apply to all element who have the `class` `para` instead of the `ID` because i have more than one element where i need to apply my CSS animation.
Thanks in Advance for your help :)

The Css :

```
@keyframes inputapparition {
    0%   
    {
        opacity: 0;

    }
    100% 
    {

        opacity: 1;

    }

}
.exeInputapparition
{
    animation-name: inputapparition;

        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#para 
{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto"
    font-size: 20px;

    opacity: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Animation onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847996/css-animation-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

The function `querySelectorAll` returns all elements, it's a "DOM array", therefore there isn't the attribute `className`. You should loop the list and change one by one:

```
var allElementsPara = document.querySelectorAll(".para");

for (var i = allElementsPara.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    allElementsPara.item(i).classList.add("exeInputapparition");
};
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("#para") ...how can all elements have same id? Is it not against standard ?

Comment: It is. But the question is asking for:

> To apply a css animation on my element who has the ID para.

Comment: I guess this is the question............
 "i wanted to know if it's possible to apply to all element who have the class para instead of the ID"

Comment: Ohn, that's true. Hahah. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `document.querySelectorAll`

```
    var x=document.querySelectorAll(".para");
   for(var a =0;a<x.length;a++){
   x[a].classList.add("exeInputapparition")
  }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dr4mznkr/1/)

[JSFIDDLE WITH .para](https://jsfiddle.net/dr4mznkr/2/)

Comment: I tried like this but it's not working document.querySelectorAll('para').className ='exeInputapparition';

Comment: are you missing the dot(.) before class?

Comment: it's
document.QuerySelectorAll(".exeInputapparition");

or like this:
var animatedEls = document.getElementsByClassName("exeInputapparition");
var index = 0, length = animatedEls.lenght;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    animatedEls[index].addEventListener("click",
        function () {
      
        your function(this);
    
        }
    );
}

Comment: I updated my code with the CSS so you can see better :)

Comment: When i do this the animation is executed directly when the page is refresh not when i click

Comment: Ok, al these answers are no good, I am doing a codepen for you right now.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` is unique. You must use a same class for all element that you want to animate. For all element, put the class `animate` and edit the function

```
function ani(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('animate').className ='exeInputapparition';
}
```

Comment: Tried your way but not working.Here is jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dr4mznkr/5/.
Also It is getElementsByClassName and not getElementByClass

Comment: I tried it seems like it doesnt recognize the element :(

Comment: It would be getElementsByClassName, but either way, you want the class added on click, hold on, i will do a codepen and post it as answer.

Comment: Sorry for the `getElementsByClass`.

Comment: this can't work, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of DOM elements, the array has not the property `className`

Answer (score 0):

You can disregard the previous answers, people did and could not know what exactly you want before you posted the css.
You do not the keyframes for this.
Here is a full JS solution, as you need JS for this anyway.

```
document.querySelector(".reveal3").addEventListener("click", function(){
  toggle();
});
function toggle(){
  var c = document.querySelector(".reveal3");
  if(c.style.opacity == 1){
    c.style.opacity = 0;
  } else {
    c.style.right = "0px"; 
    c.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

See it in action here, the div on the right side, click on it to toggle visibility.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/GopoJB

Comment: Just an improvement: you may use `evt.target` instead of `var c = ...`, in this way the `toggle` function would refer to the target of the click and you don't have to query two times the same element.

Answer (score 0):

A more performing solution would be to apply the class to the `body` element.
Every access to the DOM takes some ms and when your web page becomes huge, with a lot of JavaScript, it can get slow.

Accessing a single DOM element (`<body>`) instead `N` elements with the given class will:

1. reduce the number of accesses to the DOM;
2. reduce to 0 the queries you perform on the DOM;
3. make sure all the elements starts appearing at the same time;
4. assure that every element with the class `para` added after the script has run, will have the correct style;

```js
// here I use a `setTimeout` to make the function start automatically
// logically you can take the content of this function and put it
// wherever you prefer
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.className += ' in';
}, 1000);
```

```css
.para {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.in .para {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="para">para 1</div>
<div class="para">para 2</div>
<div class="para">para 3</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this solution will help your.it is easy to use jquery with this.I have implemented for a `div`.you can use it for image also.so try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="clickme" style="background-color:orange;width:100px;height:100px;">
<!--use <img src="imageurl"/> here-->
</div>


<!-- js--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
      $(this).animate({opacity:0.5},1000);
    });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why include jQuery and use JavaScript to perform an animation when you can do it all with just few lines of CSS and 1 line of JS?

Comment: It's overkill using all this stuff for a so simple task.