# How to animate a class on click using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that I wanted to animate when I click another `div`. I know this can be done easily with jQuery, but somehow I could not get it work.

I have tried the SO suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847996/css-animation-onclick) to add

```
$('#button').onClick(function(){
$('#target_element').addClass('.animate_class_name');});
```

but nothing happened.

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rdfbcq3j/2/. The goal is to animate the red circle div object into a rectangle when `click_me` is pushed. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have syntactically mistake in your script, no need to add `.` before the class name in `addClass()` function. A working fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/raushankumar/rdfbcq3j/4/) Use like this

```
$('#button').on("click",function(){
    $('#target_element').addClass('animate_class_name'); 
});
```

or,

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#target_element').addClass('animate_class_name'); 
});
```

or,

```
$(document).on("click","#button",function(){
    $('#target_element').addClass('animate_class_name'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just misspelled a little with dots. Here is the working jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rdfbcq3j/3/

It should be `$('.circle').addClass('clicked');`, not `$('circle').addClass('.clicked');`

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with your code and there was a syntax problem, I removed the **dot** on clicked.  And I used **click()** instead of onClick.  This should fix your problem.

```
 $('.circle').addClass('clicked');
```

Javascript

```
$('.click_me').click(function(){
    $('.circle').addClass('clicked');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="click_me"> Click Me!
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .circle {
      position: absolute;
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: red;
    }

    .clicked {
      animation: rectangularize 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    }

    .click_me {
      position: absolute;
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      left: 50%;
      background: yellow;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    @keyframes rectangularize {
      30% {
        border-radius: 0%;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt put a '.' to query the 'circle' element from the DOM and so on. Here is your solved code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsbcc3rz/

```
$('.click_me').on('click', function() {

    $('.circle').addClass('clicked');
});
```