# After pressing button the animation does not repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css

What am I doing wrong, that after pressing the button the animation does not repeat? Thanks for help.

```js
var  abox = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
function allmove(){
       abox.classList.toggle("move");
}
```

```css
.vector img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes example{
    0%{left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%{left:200px; top:0px;}
    100%{left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="vector">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSqYooppFTzO8AydhbeZtjnrWpeZS5b7Gbi9EnwEPuuPW_t6ycn" />
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="allmove()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: can we see your .move class ?

Comment: @CedricGourville  This is all code inspired by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251634/12130396

Comment: I need to know if in your .move class you have set the example keyframes animation? like in the .vector class

Comment: I do not have .move class , I used it as in the example in js

Comment: You'are asking javascript to toggle .move class

Comment: can this code be modified to make it work?

Comment: Hmm try to read your code and understand what your doing

Comment: I want the animation to be done again after pressing the button, I know my code is wrong and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to refresh animation on click.

I added .animation class to separate it from vector class.This way you can easly toggle it.

the setTimeout is to wait a moment before adding the class after removing it.

```js
var  abox = document.getElementsByClassName("animation")[0];
function allmove(){
    abox.classList.remove("animation");
    setTimeout(function(){ abox.classList.add('animation') }, 100);
}
```

```css
    .vector img {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;
        position: relative;
 
    }
    .animation img {
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes example{
        0%{left:0px; top:0px;}
        25%{left:200px; top:0px;}
        100%{left:0px; top:0px;}
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="vector animation">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSqYooppFTzO8AydhbeZtjnrWpeZS5b7Gbi9EnwEPuuPW_t6ycn" />
    </div>
    <button class="button" onclick="allmove()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it, but I think addEventListener is better than onclick()

I modify a bit your code

You can find jsfiddle example Here

```js
const bike = document.querySelector(".bike");
const button = document.querySelector(".button");

function allMove(){
       bike.classList.toggle("move");
}

button.addEventListener('click', allMove);
```

```css
.vector img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    
}

.move{
  
     animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes example{
    0%{left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%{left:200px; top:0px;}
    100%{left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="vector">
  <img class="bike" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSqYooppFTzO8AydhbeZtjnrWpeZS5b7Gbi9EnwEPuuPW_t6ycn" />
</div>
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mehdi Ayari's answer, but I think using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is  better than using a timeout.

```js
var abox = document.querySelector(".animation");
function allmove() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    abox.classList.remove("animation");
    requestAnimationFrame(() => abox.classList.add("animation"));
  });
}
```

```css
.vector img {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;
        position: relative;
 
    }
    .animation img {
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes example{
        0%{left:0px; top:0px;}
        25%{left:200px; top:0px;}
        100%{left:0px; top:0px;}
    }
```

```html
 <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="vector animation">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSqYooppFTzO8AydhbeZtjnrWpeZS5b7Gbi9EnwEPuuPW_t6ycn" />
    </div>
    <button class="button" onclick="allmove()">Click Me</button>
```